# An ex-friend? A prior friend?

Tags: pronouns

Could anyone give me an idea of how you would refer to someone who was your friend, but is no longer?
She is an ex-friend of mine? A prior friend? Something else?

Thanks!

Comment: She **used to be** my friend/a friend (of mine), or simply: *She was my friend.* An "ex-friend" is also acceptable. This question is better suited to our sister site ELL. I have asked the mods to migrate your question there.

Comment: "erstwhile" is a rather old word meaning "former" so either of those would work.

Comment: Heavens preserve us from "prior" used to mean "previous", which doesn't quite work here anyway. I don't answer questions in comments, so I won't say what does, as I have added my vote to the migration to ELL.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context:

If the person is no longer your friend because they are deceased, then use the term "late friend" *(most people would understand that they are not merely tardy)*

If the person is no longer your friend because of some kind of falling out, then the term "former friend" is appropriate, as is your suggestion of "ex-friend".

**EDIT#1:**

See:

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ex-)

Comment: @JJJ 's response to MusicandTeaLady's answer applies equally well to yours. How does the poster or anyone else know whether your answer is right or not? If I disagree and don't back my opinion with definitions and usage examples, how does anyone know if I am right? A pain, when you are a native English speaker and know what you would say yourself, but that is the way SE ELU works, and has to work.

Comment: @David  I will attempt to find an authoritative reference and examples

Answer (score 0):

I tend not to use "ex-friend", as it tends to break up a sentence and does flow as well, and also could lead readers to focus more on what happened between you two, instead of the rest of the sentence. A "former friend" flows well together, is formal, and, for bonus points, has alliteration.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please consider adding sources to support your answers.

Answer (score 0):

One possible term is "[bygone](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bygone)." Depending on the connotation you want and the circumstances of the ending of the friendship, the term "lost friend / lost friendship" [seems common](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=lost%20friend,former%20friend,ex-friend)

Comment: I'm not a fan of using Trends for stuff like this. In the search "lost friend", I suspect that most of the time "lost" is intended to be a verb, but we can't know because there is no broader context and we can't read minds.

Comment: I agree with you @Laurel but in this case I had a hard time sharing pertinent search *results* and N-grams was useless. barring the variability of google, you could go search "lost friend(ship)" and see results where the usage is a melange of verb, adjective, and grammatically incorrect. Do you think it would help if I included a screenshot of those search results instead?

Comment: My go to is usually [COCA/BNC](https://corpus.byu.edu/) (however when I searched COCA for "lost friend" it was clear that most of the results were for friends that were long lost, missing, or dead). For less common usages, you can use a search engine to find examples of the word being used this way and include that as evidence (I call this the "[descriptivist approach](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11265/191178)").

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an “old friend”. Although this can be used to signify a former friend, it can also however be interpreted as a “long-time friend” or an elderly friend.